# What all does node_save do?

Tags: 7, nodes

What all does `node_save` do? Is there a comprehensive list somewhere? What all happens besides saving all the field data to the db and calling `hook_node_save`?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the source of the [node_save](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_save/7) function, you will see that it does a bunch of things, among others:

- Resetting entity cache
- Calling presave hooks
- Updating access role tables
- Saving revisions
- etc...